# Auto Layout views with animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, autolayout

I have a custom view , CustomLayout (blue, custom UIView), and this view contains 3 subviews vertical aligned by using constraints (Layout Anchors), each view are aligned following this order:

- 1 view: SlideLayout (red, custom UIView)
- 2 view: UIButton (yellow)
- 3 view: UIView (dry gray)

I want when I clicked on the button (yellow), the height size of SlideLayout (red) increase if open or decrease if close by using animation. And other views must change position during animation and the parent view (CustomLayout) must increase/decrease his height size (animation) if SlideLayout increase/decrease.

What method is called when I use this method:

> UIView.animate(withDuration, delay, options, animations, completion)

I override **layoutIfNeeded()** method by adding a simple print but it does not call every time during animation

I try this but It doesn’t work as I expect. How I can fix that thank you.

[Bad animation in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MwP9.png)

Codes:

```
class CustomLayout: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        onLayout()
    }

    public func onLayout() {
        print("\(frame.size.height)")
        let MARGIN: CGFloat = 10
        for i in 0 ..< subviews.count {
            let child = subviews[i]
                if i == 0 { // slide layout
                    child.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                    child.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: MARGIN).isActive = true
                    child.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
                    child.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: frame.size.width - (MARGIN * 2)).isActive = true
                    let enchorHeight = child.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: child.frame.size.height);
                    enchorHeight.isActive = true
                    (subviews[0] as! SlideDownLayout).enchorHeight = enchorHeight
                }
                else if i == 1 { // button
                    child.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                    child.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subviews[0].bottomAnchor, constant: MARGIN).isActive = true
                    child.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
                    child.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: child.frame.size.width).isActive = true
                    child.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: child.frame.size.height).isActive = true

                }
                else if i == 2 { // uiview  
                    child.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false    
                    child.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subviews[1].bottomAnchor, constant: MARGIN).isActive = true                
                    child.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true                
                    child.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: frame.size.width - (MARGIN * 4)).isActive = true 
                    child.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true               
                    bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: child.bottomAnchor, constant: MARGIN).isActive = true

                }        
        }    
    }
}

class SlideDownLayout: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    private var HEIGHT: CGFloat = 0
    private var isClosed: Bool = true

    private func setup() {
        HEIGHT = frame.height
        frame.size.height = 0
    }

    public func slideAnimation(view: UIView) {
        print("\(HEIGHT)")
        isClosed = !isClosed
        self.enchorHeight!.constant = self.isClosed ? 0 : self.HEIGHT
         UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
            view.layoutIfNeeded()
         }, completion: nil)
    }

    override func layoutIfNeeded() {
        print("...")
        super.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    var enchorHeight: NSLayoutConstraint? = nil
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var customLayout: CustomLayout!
    @IBOutlet weak var slideDownLayout: SlideDownLayout!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        customLayout.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        customLayout.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        customLayout.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        customLayout.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        customLayout.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true

    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

    @IBAction
    func buttonListener(_ sender: Any) {
        slideDownLayout.slideAnimation(view: self.view)
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this using stackView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to make a dynamic View don't change frame but change constraint's constant as frame doesn't push the parent down , so make the height constraint of the view you want to animate as **IBOutlet** and control it's constant value

You can try

```
class CustomLayout: UIView {

   var heightCon:NSLayoutConstraint!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        onLayout()
    }

    public func onLayout() {
        print("\(frame.size.height)")
        let MARGIN: CGFloat = 10
        for i in 0 ..< subviews.count {
            let child = subviews[i]
                if i == 0 { // slide layout
                    child.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                    child.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: MARGIN).isActive = true
                    child.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
                    child.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: frame.size.width - (MARGIN * 2)).isActive = true
                   heightCon =  child.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: child.frame.size.height) 
                   heightCon.isActive = true 
                }
```

//

```
    public func slideAnimation() {
        print("\(HEIGHT)")

         isClosed = !isClosed

         let ss = self.superview as! CustomLayout

         ss.heightCon.constant = self.isClosed ? 0 : self.HEIGHT

         UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: { 
            ss.layoutIfNeeded()
         }, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: thank you, I dont see you code update I did what you say and the animation work but the parent size does not increase or decrease, I update my code

Comment: hook the bottom constraint of the bottom-most view to it

Comment: I update my code, I had bottom constraint but the view does not start from top when is open and the bottom margin exceed parent view

Comment: set height for view at i = 2

Comment: if child heightAnchor I did

Comment: put self.view.layoutIfNeeded() after  slideDownLayout.slideAnimation() , or send it as paremter and relayout it there

Comment: sry it change by adding parameter and call for animation closure but the margin of the last view (child  i = 2 in CustomLayout) exceed

Comment: send a repo so i can closely look at

Comment: put the constant change out of the animation

Comment: put this line ** self.enchorHeight!.constant = self.isClosed ? 0 : self.HEIGHT** above UIView.animate

Comment: I did, I update the code but does not work the margin still exceed

Comment: you still have same output that in pic ??

Comment: thank you for your help I replace this line "child.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: MARGIN).isActive = true" by "bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: child.bottomAnchor, constant: MARGIN).isActive = true" (child i = 2 CustmLayout) and now it works fine

Comment: Also i recommend setting constraints in code or use stackviews for such tasks it would be easier and lower possibility of logical errors